# Starting a PHP session on a jQuery function event

Tags: php, javascript, session, session-variables

I've got a simple jQuery function and at a certain point (let's say on a button click) I'd like to start a PHP session.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".loginPopupButton").click(function(){
            //here I'd need a way to trigger the session.
        });
    });
```

I would assume starting a session from PHP can be done as easily as changing a PHP variable. For example - the PHP can be something like:

```
    <?php
        $testVar = null;
        if(isset($testVar)){
            session_start()
            $_SESSION['sessionStarted'] = $testVar;
        }

    ?>
```

Is there a way for such as session to be started?

Comment: PHP code doesn't run on the client, you need to use JQuery to send a message to the server to init the session - have a look at JQuery Ajax

Comment: you would be best off sending a request to the server. don't mix server and client code in the same script. Have you read much about ajax?

Comment: put into click trigger some redirect like index.php?session=true and then if($_GET['session'] == 'true')  { session_start(); ..... }  btw. you have forgotten semicolon in session_start();

Comment: Cheers guys - I think Ajax is key here - I'm looking into it now. I'm not sure about appending to the URL @WigglerJtag - wouldn't this mean users can start the session without necessarily clicking the button, but instead entering the URL directly? That would not be ideal.

Comment: no, because you add then next check, if(isset($_SESSION['sessionStarted'])) { echo 'session is already started u hax0r'; }

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['login'])) { 
        if(isset($_SESSION['sessionStarted'])) {
            echo 'session is already set';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['sessionStarted'] = $testVar;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and client-side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loginPopupButton").click(function(){
        //code to redirect to index.php?login=true or make some ajax GET call, doesnt matter
    });
});
```

then you can add like php checks, if session exists, do not echo loginPopupButton and so on :)

Comment: Thanks for that! I can see how this would work if I used JS to set `login` to `true`. I'm now trying to figure out how the Ajax would look if I wanted to make an Ajax call and what I would be checking for in the php instead of the `isset($_GET['login'])`

Comment: your goal is to always call $_GET or $_POST (doesnt matter), and then you can do all the actions on the server-side (safe and secure)

Comment: Okay but how would the actual syntax look? What would I send through using Ajax? And how would I check for it on the server side? Sorry if these are n00b questions this is the first time I'm dealing with Ajax.

Comment: Sorry, but I've posted you almost 90% of the script and if you can not achieve 10% via google, then life will be hard ^^ first of all try to understand POST and GET via normal HTML, then when you get how it works, you're able to know what to call via jQuery. And if you want some syntax done hire someone on freelancer :D

Comment: In reality what I needed was the Ajax. The code you posted was pretty much what I had in the question from the start. Fair call about the Google though.

Comment: The code you posted in php was totally wrong and would not work. Does not make sence. Before IF statement you assign always null and then you try to make IF, it will never work. Byes

Comment: With a bit of tweaking it was pretty much on the right track. I got it working now and the code you posted was nowhere near 90% for what I needed. Calling it 90% to then say get a freelancer was a cheap move.

Comment: If the code i posted you not correct, then your description of what you need failed + your code that you posted failed twice. So post your new code and show it here + mark it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Umm..okay.. My question is perfectly fine - if you can't understand what's being asked that's fine. Other commenters seemed to understand perfectly fine what the solution should be - which by the way is what lead me to solving my problem.

Comment: 'post your new code and show it here + mark it as answer' - thats how stackoverflow works, instead of posting rude comments.

Comment: 1st comment solved my problem already I don't see why I need to post new code to suit your answer.